# Can't set range variable to ActiveCell.Offset

Tags: vba, range, cell

As far as I know, this should be a working syntax. However, when I run this, I get:

> Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

```
Dim rngColor as Range
Set rngColor = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1))
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete the range() and simply, as

```
Dim rngColor as Range
Set rngColor = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Silly mistake on my part

Answer (score 0):

`As far as I know, this should be a working syntax` Not quite.
According this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178282(v=office.12).aspx), there are various ways to work on Range.

1. *expression*.**Range**(arg) - `arg` is in the form of string

   ```
   Set rngColor = Range(Activecell.Offset(0, 1).Address) ' correct way
   ```
2. *expression*.**Range**(*cells(1)*,*cells(2))* - `cells(1)` and `cells(2)` can be objects

   ```
   With Activecell
       Set rngColor = Range(.Offset(0, 1), .Offset(0, 1)) ' using Activecell object
   End With
   ```

You are trying to use No.1 syntax above which will not accept `Objects` as argument.
If you want to pass `Activecell` as is, you should use No.2 syntax.
But still, to do what you want, [user's answer is the best way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29504155/2685412).